# How do I delete a space in a char array?

Tags: c

I got as far as counting the length, and the number of characters and i reversed it.
So from here how do i delete the spaces in kimenet[]?

I tried checking if there's a space in the char array but couldn't figure out what to do after that.

```
void titkosit(char input[], char output[]) {
    int length = 0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int letters=0;
    while (input[i] != '\0') {
        length++;
    }

    for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        output[j] = input[i];
    }
    j++;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if ((input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'z') || 
            (input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'Z')) {
            letters++;
            if (input[i] == ' ') {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Martin32 Could you explain how this loop     for (i = hossz - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        kimenet[j] = bemenet[i];
    } copies a string in the reverse order?

Comment: Is this function ONLY required to copy `input` to `output`, but in reverse order and with spaces removed? I'm just trying to figure out if you strictly need to be counting the length and the number of non-space characters.

Comment: Do you [just] want to _remove_ spaces (in addition to counting letters)? That is: `input = "hello world"` --> `output = "helloworld"`?

Comment: @CraigEstey I think they want `input = "hello world"` --> `output = "dlrowolleh"`.

Comment: Probably so. The function name `titkosit` means secret, so it's presumably some simple cipher.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yup. To OP: this can be done better/easier in a _single_ loop (if we _don't_ count the loop to get the `length` which can be replaced with `strlen`). Don't copy a space to the output in the first place rather than trying to remove it from `output` in a separate loop.

Comment: More specific to the question: https://godbolt.org/z/Gq8a1re89

Comment: @jarmod yup, it is.

Comment: @CraigEstey  i want to count how long each word is (if there are multiple) in the char array.

Comment: What do you want to count? The number of alpha letters (as you're doing with `letters++`)? Or, also, the number of spaces (for which you'd need a separate counter)?

Comment: Refactored: `void titkosit(char input[], char output[]) { int length = 0; int i = 0; int j = 0; int letters = 0;  while (input[i] != '\0') { length++; }  for (i = length - 1;  i >= 0;  --i) { int chr = input[i];  if ((chr >= 'A') && (chr <= 'Z')) ++letters;  if ((chr >= 'a') && (chr <= 'z')) ++letters;  if (chr != ' ') output[j++] = chr; }  output[j] = 0; }`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow :):):)